# Can a SQlite database connection opened on a button click be closed in another button click

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I have opened a SQLite database connection on a button click (Start button).

```
Configurations m_Config;
SQLiteConnection ^conn;
conn = gcnew SQLiteConnection(m_Config.connectionString); 
conn->Open();
```

I want close the same connection when Stop button is clicked. Is it possible ?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: BTW, its an MFC application. Tried creating a global variable for SQLiteConnection. But errors are shown when compiled.

Comment: Don't comment on your question, instead edit it to make it clearer. That said, this isn't C++! I think it's a Microsoft invention call C++/CLI, I'm not sure though. Please fix the tag accordingly, too. That said, the answer to your question is "Yes" (just store the connection object somewhere accessible in both button handlers).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MFC, you probably already have some window or dialog class with an onClick-handler. Just make the `conn` variable a member variable of that class.

Comment: Yes I do have a Class defined in header file.I tried to add Conn  as member variable.

Comment: class STB_Dialog : public CDialogEx
{
 DECLARE_DYNAMIC(STB_Dialog)
public:
 STB_Dialog(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
 virtual ~STB_Dialog();
 enum { IDD = IDD_STB_DIALOG };

protected:
 HICON m_hIcon;
 virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
 virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support                                                                                              
 DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
 afx_msg void OnBnClickedStart();
 afx_msg void OnBnClickedStop();
 BOOL isDatabaseOpen;
 SQLiteConnection^ conn;
};

Comment: cannot declare a managed 'conn' in an unmanaged 'STB_Dialog' may not declare a global or static variable, or a member of a native type that refers to objects in the gc heap